# How to set universal password for customers in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.7

I am running a portal where I require my customers to use default which I will be emailing to them in separate email. Can you advise how I can do this? I am running Magento Community 1.7

Comment: My previous coder had configured the same, but I want to change that default password and email only active customers with new password.

Comment: I would advise against using a default password. It only takes one person registering twice to realize and exploit. If you're dead set on it you need to configure an observer for customer-registration-success: http://technet.weblineindia.com/web/magento-event-observers-for-customer-registration-success/